# Operator Stacking in C#

Tags: c#, operators

Being pivot an Int32, why does C# give me an error when I type the line

```
++this.pivot %= 21;
```

?

It says that

> the left-hand side must be a variable, property or indexer.

But it should be perfectly fine as that Unary Operator takes precedence over anything else and its result is calculate before attempting the modulus one.

Still, it does not work. It also does not work if I put it within parenthesis.

Why is that? Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: ++X is a **method** (basically) , what append when you have this: `PlusPlus(X)=5;` ?

Answer (score 3):

Because you are trying to do an assignment but you have a statement in left-hand side.

As you might already know, this statement :

```
this.pivot %= 21;
```

Is equivelant to:

```
this.pivot = this.pivot % 21;
```

Here the left side is a variable. `++this.pivot` returns a value not a variable. So you can't assign to a value something like this is invalid:

```
12 = this.pivot % 21;

// or
int x = 23;
++x = x % 20;
```

That's why you are getting the error message. In order to solve it you should separate your statements:

```
++this.pivot;
this.pivot %= 21;
```

Comment: you should do separate statements for the sake of readability

Answer (score 0):

You can't store the result of an expression in another expression:

Though `this.pivot` is a variable, `++this.pivot` apparently is not, and it also is no placeholder for `this.pivot` with either before or after the `%=` operation.